# Adding a button on top of loaded webpage

Tags: javascript, electron

I am loading a webpage using `loadURL` in my main window and want to have a sticky button on at the bottom right for performing some action.

1) Is there any way i can have a button or custom navbar on top of loaded webpage in my window? Currently I've made another child window with height and width same as that of button and placed it on top but it doesn't look/sound good.

2) Is there any way to load a file of mine (say xyz.html) and then just have a section where that URL is loaded, since websites don't allow their webpages to be loaded in iframe any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is there any way i can have a button or custom navbar on top of loaded webpage in my window? Currently I've made another child window with height and width same as that of button and placed it on top but it doesn't look/sound good.

Yes, this is definitely possible. The two ways that I can think of to do this include using the `preload` preference (see [webPreferences](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)) to preload some JavaScript before loading the actual page and through the [`webContents.executeJavaScript()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) function.

The latter method would look something like this:

```
win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Add your <span>sticky</span> button code here</p>');
`);
```

This method essentially injects HTML by using the [`webContents.executeJavaScript()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) function where `win` is your `BrowserWindow`.

> 2) Is there any way to load a file of mine (say xyz.html) and then just have a section where that URL is loaded, since websites don't allow their webpages to be loaded in iframe any more.

I bet there's some workaround to directly inject HTML but the methods I mentioned above (preloading or using `executeJavaScript`) would be much easier to accomplish this same task.

Hopefully, my answer could be of help.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey! i managed to get it done using webView for for the button XD. I'll try your method as well, thanks :)

Comment:  That's great to hear! Hopefully my method helped in some way, good luck!